# fundamental domain of a genus 2 closed surface in the upper half plane

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

I want to do some trial examples on a negative curved closed surface, and I think the most convenient way is to do it on a fundamental domain in the upper half plane. Could anyone tell me what a fundamental domain of a genus 2 surface would look like (the simplest one)? Thanks.